# Python - Pillow setting TIFF image resolution when saving

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tesseract

I have an OpenCV image I'm trying to save as a `.tiff` file:

```
img_to_save = Image.fromarray(array.astype("uint8"))
img_to_save.save(os.path.join(args[2], "1.tif"))
```

The file is saved but the resolution metadata is missing
`Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.` when I run tesseract on it.

I tried the following but I'm not sure how to convert resolution to dpi correctly or if it adds the metadata to the file:

```
img_to_save.save(os.path.join(args[2], "1.tif"), dpi=(array.shape[0], array.shape[1]))
```

How can I include the correct image resolution in the tiff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `dpi=(72,72)`.

Check in Terminal with:

```
exiftool YourFile.tif
```

or with **ImageMagick**:

```
magick identify -verbose YourFile.tif
```

or with:

```
tiffinfo YourFile.tif
```

Comment: Thanks, the metadata seems to be there, but why is `dpi=(72,72)` the right dpi?

Comment: If you don't know the correct dpi and you need a value, it's normally a reasonable guesstimate. Try varying it through 144, 288, 600 and see what results you get.